# Running JOIN on sample datasets in GoogleBigQuery

Tags: syntax, google-bigquery

I am evaluating the Google BigQuery platform in comparison to SQL Server for analyzing my website data. I was trying to run the following query on sample datasets provided by them, however I am not sure why I get an error

```
(SELECT corpus, sum(word_count) AS wordcount 
FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare GROUP BY corpus) as set1
join
(SELECT corpus as corpus2, sum(word_count) AS wordcount2
FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare where corpus = 'hamlet' GROUP BY corpus ) as set2
on set1.wordcount = set2.wordcount2;
```

Error:

> Encountered " "AS" "as "" at line 2, column 78. Was expecting: EOF

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance
Shilpi

Answer (score 2):

you miss a select phrase...

```
select * from 
(SELECT corpus, sum(word_count) AS wordcount 
 FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare 
 GROUP BY corpus) as set1 
join 
(SELECT corpus as corpus2, sum(word_count) AS wordcount2 
 FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare where corpus = 'hamlet' 
 GROUP BY corpus ) as set2 
 on set1.wordcount = set2.wordcount2;
```